# PHP PayPal SDK new design

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

When I try to checkout with PayPal I still receive the old design. How to switch over to the new one?

```
$sdkConfig = array(
    'mode' => 'sandbox',
);

$cred = new OAuthTokenCredential("CLIENT ID", "SECRET", $sdkConfig);

$apiContext = new ApiContext($cred, 'Request' . time());
$apiContext->setConfig($sdkConfig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new PayPal Design isn't available in Sandbox mode yet.

```
$sdkConfig = array(
    'mode' => 'live',
);

$cred = new OAuthTokenCredential("CLIENT ID", "SECRET", $sdkConfig);

$apiContext = new ApiContext($cred, 'Request' . time());
$apiContext->setConfig($sdkConfig);
```